# Inserting data from textbox into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I don't know where the problem is. I'm trying to insert data from the textbox to the database and I get an error as shown below.

This is my code

```
private void but_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String query = "INSERT INTO Tbl_Cashier (FName, MName, LName, Address, ContactNo, Email, Age, Gender, Password, role) VALUES (@FName, @MName, @LName, @Address, @ContactNo, @Email, @Age, @Gender, @Password, @role)";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", txb_Fname);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MName", txb_Mname);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", txb_Lname);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txb_Address);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", txb_ContactNo);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txb_Email);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txb_Age);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", txb_Gander);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txb_Password);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", txb_Role);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: Use  `txb_name.Text`.  Also, you're executing your query *twice* with `ExecuteNonQuery()` and `ExecuteScalar()`.  Drop the scalar execution.

Comment: oh okay ^^ ill try

Comment: thank you so much ^^ i got it , i almost going to ask you about why it became twice . thanks again^^.

Comment: Kudos on using paramaterized SQL as well. :D

Comment: You **don't need** to have both  `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteScalar` - if you run both, you're inserting the data twice. Just use `ExecuteNonQuery()` **only** (which is the command to run an `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE` - something that doesn't return a result set)

Comment: OP is probably not inserting the data twice, thanks to natural key constraint... I hope.

Comment: Seeing button_click code in the same procedure as SqlConnection hurts my eyes.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx#Layers   Please look at laying your application.  Even if you're a newbie.

Comment: okay ^^ thanks ill study about it

Answer (score 5):

You need to add .Text end of control.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", txb_Fname.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MName", txb_Mname.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", txb_Lname.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txb_Address.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", txb_ContactNo.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txb_Email.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txb_Age.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", txb_Gander.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txb_Password.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", txb_Role.Text);
```